# When Gravity Form is submitted then reveal content on same page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Using Wordpress with Divi Theme.

When Gravity Form submit button is pressed and submitted I also want it to reveal a section on the same page. Like a toggle reveal that submits the form at the same time.

I Enabled AJAX so the page doesn't refresh after submission but don't know how to reveal a section of page and submit at the same time. Any help welcome Thanks.

Comment: You want to reveal data from the submitted form or you want to reveal some other content like a success message?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. The easiest would be to put the section you want to reveal in the confirmation box within gravity forms. Alternatively you can have the confirmation process re-direct to a specific page that has the same information as your first page, but with the new content on it as well. Finally, (most complex but also most secure) you can setup the gravity forms to also add the user to a member group (using the "Groups" plugin), then have that groups plugin show and hide info based on group membership.